# How to use for loop inside fwrite()

Tags: php

```
$open = fopen("../../users/".$acc_det['initial_id']."/info/".$date."index.html", "w");
fwrite($open, "
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'>
    <head></head>
    <body>
<p>
"for($i=0, $i<10,$i++){echo$i;}"
    </body>

</p>
</body>
</html>"
?>
```

Wish to use loop to write numbers from 1 to 10 using for loop in a HTML file

Comment: And what's your question about this? Anything not working with the given code?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are looking for.

```
$content = '';
for($i=0, $i<10,$i++)
    $content .= $i;

$open = fopen("../../users/".$acc_det['initial_id']."/info/".$date."index.html", "w");
fwrite($open, "
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'>
    <head></head>
    <body>
<p>$content</p>
</body>
</html>"
?>
```

You cannot run a for loop while constructing a string like this, however you can insert other strings (as shown in above example) or call functions which return a string.

The same code with the function example:

```
function countToTen()
{
    $content = '';
    for($i=0, $i<10,$i++)
        $content .= $i;
    return $content;
}

$open = fopen("../../users/".$acc_det['initial_id']."/info/".$date."index.html", "w");
fwrite($open, "
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'>
    <head></head>
    <body>
<p>".countToTen()."</p>
</body>
</html>"
?>
```

Please mind, that for 'calling a function' you actually need to leave the 'literal string'. For inserting a variable value, you don't have to do that.

Comment: You should add a space between the numbers for him.  Or maybe a <br>

Comment: Yes, @RohitGupta I agree that would be better for the readability of the output, but I think such menial additions should be well within the scope of the OP's abilities.

Comment: Don't bet on it :-)

Comment: Oh, I am not 'betting' on anything, no worries. But I'm an optimist and want to give their abilities the benefit of the doubt. If they run into more trouble, I am sure they will ask again. :)